# How to completely remove spacing in between two widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to remove any bit of space in between multiple widgets in order to create a custom TextField according to my UI.
also if im suggested any packages to do the same, it will be really helpful !
Row
--text
--textField
--text

**My goal:**

[image: Required UI]

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
      width: 392.72727272727275,
      height: 40,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(
          top: BorderSide.none,
          left: BorderSide.none,
          right: BorderSide.none,
          bottom: BorderSide.none,
        ),
      ),
      child: const Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          const Text(
            '|',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 1.8),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 392.72727272727275 - 42.5,
              child: TextField(
//                 controller: controller,
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide:
                        BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 1),
                  ),
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide:
                        BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 1),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const Text(
            '|',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

This statement indicates the intent to design a customized TextField widget while paying close attention to the spacing between the individual widgets involved in its composition. The primary objective is to precisely match the desired User Interface (UI) layout, ensuring that there are no visible gaps or unnecessary padding between the constituent widgets.

Comment: I think you may need to replace `UnderlineInputBorder` with your own custom `InputBorder`.  Fortunately the source for `UnderlineInputBorder` and `OutlineInputBorder` is available to guide you.

Comment: See also the custom MessageBorder in this post: https://maylau.hashnode.dev/playing-around-with-shapeborder

Answer (score 0):

Using Row still contains a tiny space. Row(Text+Expanded(TextFiled)+Text). You can play with Transform or  you can use Stack widget.

```dart
const borderText = Text('|', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white));
    return SizedBox(
      // alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
      // width: 392.72727272727275,
      width: 400,
      height: 40,
      child: const Stack(
        children: [
          Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft, child: borderText),
          Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomRight, child: borderText),
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 1.8, // 1.8 
            child: TextField(
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 1),
                ),
                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 1),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SizedBox(
child: TextField()

)
```

Sized Box you can avoid unnecessary padding of the widget

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to draw the decoration by using `CustomPaint` instead of using `Text`, here is my demo code

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.black87,
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: DecorationPainter(),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 392.72727272727275 - 42.5,
                height: 40,
                child: TextField(
//                 controller: controller,
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DecorationPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..strokeWidth = 2
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    final path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, size.height / 2);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height / 2);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```